# How is memory allocated in case of a pointer function like this one?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm a beginner in C programming and I just started learning the concept of pointers. Could someone explain why my code ends in a segmentation fault while I think I'm doing it right? 
Maybe I'm lacking some memory allocation concepts and I hope someone here could explain them in detail or point me to link where I can find explanations for problems like mine.

```
char strs(char *s, char *k)
{
    int flag=0;
    do
    {
        if(*k=='\0') return (*(s-flag));
        if(*s==*k)
        {
            k++;
            flag++;
        }
        if(flag!=0 && *s!=*k)
        {
            k=k-flag;
        }   
        s++;
    } while(*s!='\0');
    return('\0');
}

main()
{
    char s[10],k[5];
    printf("Please enter the main string: ");
    scanf("%s",s);
    printf("Please enter the key string: ");
    scanf("%s",k);
    if((strs(s,k))!='\0') printf("The pointer is at <<<%s>>> in %s",strs(s,k),s);
    if((strs(s,k)=='\0')) printf("\nKey string not found, value of strs is %s", strs(s,k));
}
```

Comment: Please don't learn from any resource that claims `main()` without return type is valid C.

Comment: Assuming you are using the `gcc` compiler, you should pass the option `-Wall`. That will give you some very useful warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strs function returns a char but you're trying to output it using the %s format specifier.  To output a single char use %c:

```
printf("The pointer is at <<<%c>>> in %s",strs(s,k),s);
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't pay attention to the format spec and was focusing on other stuff, trying to find errors in my code.

Comment: @limitedinfinity You should pay attention to the debugger and stack trace; they will tell you what function you crashed in ... don't just assume it.